# Laravel Symfony Process doesn't stop

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, symfony-process

I'm trying to run the following script in a Laravel controller:

```
public function importLinkedin(Request $request)
{
    $process = new Process("node node/test.js");
    $process->run();

    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }
    echo $process->getOutput();
}
```

If I run the following command from terminal I get the expected output

```
node /var/www/website/public/node/test.js
```

When running the script from the Laravel controller the browser doesn't stop loading until it times out. (504 Gateway Time-out)

test.js file looks like this

```
const scrapedin = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapedin')
  const fs = require('fs')

  const cookies = fs.readFileSync('/usr/cookies.json')
  const options = {
    cookies: JSON.parse(cookies)
  }

scrapedin(options)
.then((profileScraper) => profileScraper('https://www.linkedin.com/in/profile-url/'))
.then((profile) => console.log(profile))
```

Comment: your node process has no exit. so it keeps running and the php process is still waiting on it to finish

Comment: Thank you, adding: .then(process.exit) fixed it.